# How to use macro in lua

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

Was looking now few threads on lua and found this post very interesting:

[Alert messages for lua functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652665/alert-messages-for-lua-functions/33655587?noredirect=1#comment55085565_33655587)

I am trying to use the same macro to my code with some changes to operation:

```
#define GET_INTEGER_WARN(ind, fld) do { \
lua_getfield(L, ind, #fld); \
p->##fld = lua_tointeger(L, -1); \
\
if (!lua_isinteger(L, -1)) \
    printf(#fld" allows only numbers;"); \
} while (0)
```

my code:

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, "wooxy_value"); 
p->wooxy_value = lua_tointeger(L, -1);

lua_getfield(L, -2, "wooxy_type"); 
p->wooxy_type = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
```

I changed my code as the author explain, thus:

```
GET_INTEGER_WARN(-1, "wooxy_value");  
GET_INTEGER_WARN(-2, "wooxy_type");
```

More macro error occurs at the following location:

```
p->##fld = lua_tointeger(L, -1); \
```

compilation erro: `error c2059 syntax error 'string'`

I did a test and replaces the function `p->##fld` by `p->wooxy_value` and it worked.

More in this way works only for a function, can anybody tell me what is wrong with the macro? The message is also appearing even using integer value.

Comment: Look at my updated version of my answer. I fixed the string constant problem there (after a follow up question... which looked an **awful** lot like this question) was asked and answered.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't see before.

Answer (score 3):

Using string literal makes no sense:

```
GET_INTEGER_WARN(-1, "wooxy_value");
```

results in

```
p->"wooxy_value" = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
```

Drop the quotes:

```
GET_INTEGER_WARN(-1, wooxy_value);
```